# Ruby: Add methods into an object to return simple numeric values

Tags: ruby, dynamic, mixins

I'm using ruby 1.8.6 (don't go there).  Let's say I have an array called results:  I want it to respond to a new method "current_page", which just returns a number.

When I set what I want this value to be, I have it in a local variable, like so:

```
page = 3
```

I want to modify my array so that if I call `my_array.current_page`, I get 3 back, or whatever happens to be the value held in my local variable `page`.

What's the simplest/nicest way to do this?  I tried this:

```
@page = page
def my_array.current_page
  @page
end
```

but, when this is evaluated, `@page` might not be around.  I need to sort of "hard code" the method to return whatever the current value of @page happens to be.

It needs to be able to be different for every array object, so I can't set a class method.

It occurred to me that the best way might be to add an attr_accessor field to the Array class, and then set it:  I thought that this wouldn't work, because the my_array object had been instantiated before I modified it's class, but it does seem to work:

```
class Array; attr_accessor :current_page; end

my_array.current_page = page
my_array.current_page
=> 3
```

This actually seems to work.  But is it the nicest way?  It feels quite horrible to be monkeypatching Array in the middle of my code.

Comment: If you don't want to monkeypatch `Array`, then why are you trying to call `Array#current_page` in the first place? Can't you define some wrapper object to contain your original array?

Comment: The nicest way would be to create a wrapper as @TomLord mentioned. This will allow you to separate your pagination concerns from the native Array and will offer more flexibility if the complexity expands

Answer (score 2):

You could monkey-patch just `my_array` like this:

```
my_array = [1,4,6]
page = 3

def my_array.current_page=(num)
  @page = num
end
def my_array.current_page
  @page
end

my_array.current_page = page
p my_array.current_page  # =>3
```

Comment: could be simplified to `my_array.singleton_class.class_eval { attr_accessor :current_page }` or `a.singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :current_page)`

Comment: Thanks - even if monkey-patching isn't the best approach, I think this is what I was *trying* to do.